# Python can't find packages in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup my environment for a project but python isn't able to find the modules I've installed with pip.

I did the following:

```
mkdir helloTwitter
cd helloTwitter
virtualenv myenv
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
source myenv/bin/activate

pip install tweepy
Collecting tweepy
  Using cached tweepy-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.4.3 (from tweepy)
  Using cached requests-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 (from tweepy)
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
Installing collected packages: six, requests, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, tweepy
Successfully installed oauthlib-2.0.0 requests-2.11.1 requests-oauthlib-0.6.2 six-1.10.0 tweepy-3.5.0
```

When I try to import the module it says it cannot be found.

The first entry in $PATH is `helloTwitter/myenv/bin`
All the packages are showing up in the environments site-packages directory.
I seem to be using the right python and pip.
Which python outputs `helloTwitter/myenv/bin/python`
Which pip outputs `helloTwitter/myenv/bin/pip`

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please give us the stack trace of the import error.

Comment: Could you tell me where I find the stack trace?

Comment: >> When I try to import the module it says it cannot be found. - so how does it actually "say"?

Comment: In sublime I get an error saying the module cannot be found when I try to go to the definition.

Comment: So, it is Sublime that has an issue, or you are getting an error when launching your program which has `import tweepy` in it?

Comment: Just tried it again. This is what I get: python heyTwitter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heyTwitter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
ImportError: No module named tweepy

Comment: Just got it to work...but not in the way I wanted. The site-packages directory for the virtualenv doesn't appear in sys.path but the user one does. I deactivated the environment, installed the module using pip with the user flag, then reactivated my environment and ran the program. So I guess my question is how do I configure python to look in the site packages directory in the virtual environment instead?

Comment: Though helloTwitter/helloTwitterApp/myenv/bin appears first in my $PATH. I thought that should define where Python was looking first for packages?

Comment: Are you actually activating the virtual environment before launching `python heyTwitter.py`? If not - then you are using the python which is installed in your system, and which uses system-wide installed libraries, not the virtualenv's. So, first make sure that virtual environment is activated and accept @W. Trombone's answer, if that was the issue :)

Comment: Yes the environment is active.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're manually setting your `$PATH` to point to your virtual environment. The whole point of the `myenv/bin/activate` script is to take care of this for you.

Once you have activated your virtual environment, any package you install using pip will be placed in the relevant venv `site-packages` directory (in your case, `myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`). Things like `pip --user` are unnecessary when you are working in a virtual environment (assuming default behaviour). It's all automatic.

After running `activate`, you can check the python binary you are using with `find -iname tweepy`.

Aliases can cause issues too. `which` is an external command, and won't always pick these up. A `type -a python` will flush these out.

A quick test can be done by running `helloTwitter/myenv/bin/python -c 'import tweepy'` directly. If this behaves differently to however you are currently running python (i.e. doesn't throw an import exception), then this is your problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: type -a python
    python is /Users/Marcus/CodeProjects/helloTwitter/myenv/bin/python python is /usr/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python. I'm not sure what you mean by running python directly. I can execute a script in this directory. eg python helloTwitter.py >> prints
success

Comment: I don't get any exception or output when I try to run the import :S

Comment: On Windows, I activated the virtual environment using the activate.bat in the venv\Scripts directory. After activating the environment, even though the path variable has been updated with the Scripts directory, when I run the 'python' command, it is still using the binary in the system global path. Have you come across this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I found a solution, if not an answer.

1. I uninstalled the package and made sure it was not in system or user.
2. I re-created the virtual environment.
3. I checked that the environments python and pip were being used.
4. This time when installing my package I added the `--no-cache-dir` option. The packages install successfully. Now Python can find the package.

---

```
derptop:environmentScience Marcus$ python 
>>> from tweepy import StreamListener 
>>> StreamListener 
<class tweepy.streaming.StreamListener'>
```

I checked the `sys.path` and it now includes the `site-packages` directory from the virtual environment, where previously it was absent.

Output of `sys.path`:

```
['', ....'/Users/Marcus/CodeProjects/environmentScience/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

As far as I can tell the `sys.path` was referencing the wrong site packages directory. Though I'm not sure why. I'm wondering if pips use of the cache was causing the site-packages reference to reset to system.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you are experiencing this issue, check that after activating your environment, the subsequent `python` commands are being run using the binary in the `.venv\Scripts\Python` executable.

I've seen this strange behaviour where even after the environment is activated using the `activate.bat` file in the virtual environment, AND the path to the `Scripts\` directory is added to the system path, `python` commands still use the binary in the central Python installation in the system.

This leads to any packages being installed being installed **NOT** in the virtual environment, but in the global system location.

To work around this, when running `pip` or `python` commands after activating your environment, specify the correct path to the executable within your virtual environment, i.e.,

```
.venv\Scripts\python -m pip install setup.py
```

This should install the packages into the virtual environment and solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by change project directory. Move your project directory from desktop to another place. It helped me on Windows. I moved it from /Desktop to C:/some_folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).